# Nodejs generating duplicate http-requests

Tags: node.js, http, iot, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm using below nodejs code from this [SAP Tutorial](https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/iot-part11-hcp-services-ti.html) to read Sensor values post them per HTTP. All works pretty fine, but for the fact that every record is posted twice(see [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35IJ3.png)). I'm not versed with server-side JS and don't know why the duplicates. Agreed, the values not always the same, but for further processing I'd like to have single datasets per timestamp. Could someone please help me locate the issue and if possible, provide a solution/workaround?

Also the script reads and transmits the data every 10s.

Is there a way to set the interval to maybe 3 minutes?

I would appreciate every bit of help here as well.

```
 /*     sensorTag IR Temperature sensor example
*  Craig Cmehil, SAP SE (c) 2015
*/

/* Choose the proper HTTP or HTTPS, SAP Cloud Platform requires HTTPS */
var http = require('https');

var SensorTag = require('sensortag');
var lv_temp;
var lv_humid;
var lv_deviceid = "";
var DEBUG_VALUE = true;
var xtimestamp;
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getTime ();

// SAP Cloud Platform connection details
var portIoT = 443;
var pathIoT = '/com.sap.iotservices.mms/v1/api/http/data/';
var hostIoT = 'iotmmsXXXXXXXXXXtrial.hanatrial.ondemand.com';
var authStrIoT = 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXX';
var deviceId = 'XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX';
var messageTypeID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';

var options = {
    host: hostIoT,
  port: portIoT,
    path: pathIoT + deviceId,
    agent: false,
    headers: {
       'Authorization': authStrIoT,
       'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
     'Accept': '*/*'
    },
    method: 'POST',     
};

/***************************************************************/
/* Coding to access TI SensorTag and values of various sensors */
/***************************************************************/

console.log("If not yet activated, then press the power button.");
SensorTag.discover(function(tag) {
tag.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnected!');
    process.exit(0);
});

function connectExecute() {
    console.log('Connect Device and Execute Sensors');
    tag.connectAndSetUp(enableSensors);
}

function enableSensors() {
    /* Read device specifics */
    tag.readDeviceName(function(error, deviceName) {
        console.log('Device Name = ' + deviceName);
    });
    tag.readSystemId(function(error, systemId) {
        console.log('System ID = ' + systemId);
        lv_deviceid = systemId;
    });
    tag.readSerialNumber(function(error, serialNumber) {
        console.log('Serial Number = ' + serialNumber);
    });
    tag.readFirmwareRevision(function(error, firmwareRevision) {
        console.log('Firmware Rev = ' + firmwareRevision);
    });
    tag.readHardwareRevision(function(error, hardwareRevision) {
        console.log('Hardware Rev = ' + hardwareRevision);
    });
    tag.readHardwareRevision(function(error, softwareRevision) {
        console.log('Software Revision = ' + softwareRevision);
    });
    tag.readManufacturerName(function(error, manufacturerName) {
        console.log('Manufacturer = ' + manufacturerName);
    });
    /* Enable Sensors */
    console.log("Enabling sensors:");
    console.log('\tenableIRTemperatureSensor');
    tag.enableIrTemperature(notifyMe);
    console.log('\tenableHumidity');
    tag.enableHumidity(notifyMe);
    console.log("*********************************************");
    console.log(" To stop press both buttons on the SensorTag ");
    console.log("*********************************************");
}

function notifyMe() {
    tag.notifySimpleKey(listenForButton);
    setImmediate(function loop () {
        tag.readIrTemperature(function(error, objectTemperature, ambientTemperature){
            lv_obj = objectTemperature.toFixed(1);
            lv_ambient = ambientTemperature.toFixed(1);
            });
        tag.readHumidity(function(error, temperature, humidity) {
            lv_temp = temperature.toFixed(1);
            lv_humid = humidity.toFixed(1);
        });
        if(DEBUG_VALUE)
            console.log("Sending Data: " + lv_deviceid + " " + lv_temp + " " + lv_humid);
        setSensorData(lv_temp, lv_humid);
        setTimeout(loop, 10000);
    });
  }

function listenForButton() {
    tag.on('simpleKeyChange', function(left, right) {
        if (left && right) {
            tag.disconnect();
        }
   });
}

connectExecute();
});

/******************************************************************/
/* FUNCTION to get Temperature from the Sensor & update into HANA */
/******************************************************************/
function setSensorData(lv_temp,lv_humid){
date = new Date();
  time =date.getTime();

var data = {
    "mode":"sync",
    "messageType": messageTypeID,
    "messages": [{
        "timestamp": time,
        "temperature": lv_temp,
        "humidity": lv_humid
    }]
  };
var strData = JSON.stringify(data);
if(DEBUG_VALUE)
    console.log("Data: " + strData);
if(strData.length > 46){
    if(DEBUG_VALUE)
        console.log("Sending Data to server");
    /* Process HTTP or HTTPS request */
    options.agent = new http.Agent(options);
    var request_callback = function(response) {
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            if(DEBUG_VALUE)
                console.log("REQUEST END:", response.statusCode);
        });
        response.on('error', function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        });    
    }
    var request = http.request(options, request_callback);
    request.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
    request.write(strData);
    request.end();
}else{
    if(DEBUG_VALUE)
        console.log("Incomplete Data");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should only be posting once to the system but twice to the screen.

In the function notifyMe you need to change the line

setTimeout(loop, 10000);

Change the number to the interval you want it to delay before posting again.